# How to create UNIQUE column with JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

My POJO is using JPA and when I apply unique value in the column is not working for me I tried to use the `UniqueConstraint` and also not working for me .

below is my code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id"}),@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username"}),@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})})

    public class Users {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name="user_id",unique=true,nullable = false)
     private int UserId;

     @Column(name = "username" ,unique=true,nullable = false)
     private String Username;

     @Column(name = "email",unique=true ,nullable = false)
     private String email;

     @Column(name = "firstname",nullable = false)
     private String firstname;

     @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false)
     private String lastname;

     @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
     private String password;

     @Column(name = "active")
     private int active;

     @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinTable(name="user_role", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id"))
     private Set<Role> roles;
```

below is the generated table in the database (MySQL)

```
| users | CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  active int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  firstname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  lastname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

Hibernate log after spring start

`Hibernate: create table users (user_id integer not null, username varchar(255) not null, active integer, email varchar(255) not null, firstname varchar(255) not null, lastname varchar(255) not null, password varchar(255) not null, primary key (user_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table users drop index UKfnranlqhubvw04boopn028e6
Hibernate: alter table users add constraint UKfnranlqhubvw04boopn028e6 unique (username, email)
Hibernate: alter table users drop index UK_r43af9ap4edm43mmtq01oddj6
Hibernate: alter table users add constraint UK_r43af9ap4edm43mmtq01oddj6 unique (username)
Hibernate: alter table users drop index UK_6dotkott2kjsp8vw4d0m25fb7`

Comment: does the table exist before running the application? the `unique` property has effect only when the table doesn't exist and is created by the application.

Comment: @S.K. no it's fresh database ...JPA will create everything

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna does your table created in db contain unique index constraints ?

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna just to clarify, how did you check if unique constraints added to the table or not ?

Comment: @benjaminc  my database is fresh without any tables ,I do if unique constraints are added by issue this command  `show create table users` ,it will show how the table was created and I clearly can see unique feature are not exist in the table meta data.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there's nothing wrong with this code. `unique=true` in `@Column` is a shortcut for `@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id"}` and other particular constraints. You could only use one of them except for multiple unique constraints.

But if you are confused why the generated `CREATE TABLE` doesn't contain these unique constraints, check the log, you can find `alter table` commands just after `CREATE TABLE`.

In this case commands could be,

```
alter table users add constraint UK_some_id unique (username)
alter table users add constraint UK_some_id unique (email)
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin , I don't get exactly what you mean but I added Hibernate log during the table creation  when spring boot start to the question.

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna try removing `uniqueConstraints` of `@Table`

Comment: still the same , but I notice something the unique feature is now working in the JAVA object level,but in the database level there is unique feature ,but when I try to insert in the rest API it won't allow me .

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna is unique keys are exist in db ? what happen when insert data ? any exception ?

Comment: unique key are not existed in the DB ...but the application won't allow me pass duplicate values ,but ...if insert values directly in the DB yes I can .but from the application side I can't .

Comment: i give up the only way is to added them unique constraint  manually in the database using MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="users",uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"user_id","username","email"}))

        public class Users {
```

Comment: I tried this approach already, but unfortunately it's not working .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here, set length to your unique columns.. It worked here. Do

@Column(name = "userName", length = 50, unique = true)

Answer (score 0):

in jpa the id is already unique so to make username and email unique add the statement

```
unique=true
```

to the corresponding `@Column` annotation.

PS : remember the unique cannot be null when insert new item you should drop the table before run the application and remove `uniqueConstraints` in table annotation

Answer (score 0):

if you set unique in @Column 
that's mean **let your JPA provider create the database for you** - it will create the unique constraint on the specified column.

But after creating a database, or you alter it once created, 
**then unique doesn't have any effect**

Comment: The statements in this answer are misleading or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Set the column to have the fixed length make it work because mysql size for unique constrains limited to 1000 bytes

@Column(name = "username", length = 200, unique = true)

Answer (score 0):

Use @javax.persistence.Column(unique = true).
Dont forget to restart your application.

&& you cant alter your column if there are still duplicated values in it.
drop your table, and recreate it with your generated ddl. (if ure not usin springboot)

&& if youre using springboot, go to your `application.properties` & set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `update`

This updates the schema if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The column needs to be non nullable for it to be unique!

`@Column(unique = true)` will NOT work

`@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)` will work

Answer (score 0):

If the database or schema already exists before adding the `uniqueConstraints` then it won't work.

So drop the database or schema and run the application to create new database with these `uniqueConstraints`

```
DROP DATABASE database_name;
```